# How can I disable all textfield of my tableview cell with one switch which not member of tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `tableViewCell` with `textField` and only one switch which is not the part of `tableViewCell`.

So I want to do when switch on and off then my `tableViewCell` `textFields` disabled and enabled. So How can I do this??

```
@IBAction func switchServiceTax_Action(_ sender: UISwitch) {


    let cell : tbleCell = tblViewServices.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! tbleCell


   if switch.isOn{
        cell.txtFld.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tblView.reloadData()

   }else{
        cell.txtFld.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    tblView.reloadData()


   }
}
```

Comment: Look up notifications.

Comment: show some tried code

Comment: Read a bit more about table views and how it reuses cells. You just can't reference a cell like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use switch Object in cell for Row it. It is Simple logic write in below and follow instruction.

```
@IBAction weak var switchTextField: UISwitch!
@IBAction func switchServiceTax_Action(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    tblView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TBLcell
    cell.txtFirstName.resignFirstResponder()
    cell.txtFirstName.isUserInteractionEnabled = switchTextField.isOn
    return cell
}
```

Comment: make sure you reload tableView the key Board close, either vise textField should the entering text.

Comment: @PradipPatel - what is the use of resignFirstResponder in here

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to achieve the requirement.

1. In `cellforRow`, instead of *`if-else`* you can directly use this below line and make sure to reload the tableview everytime when switch is toggled.

`cell.txtFld.isUserInteractionEnabled = switch.isOn`

2. Just implement below **UITextFieldDelgate**, thats all. No need to reload tableview, so it increases app performance.

   ```
   func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      return switch.isOn
   }
   ```